# Authorization in ASP.NET Core razor

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, razor-pages

I have an admin area I want every user except normal user to be able o go to the admin area.

My user types are dynamic - what should I do?

My authentication is permission based.

I used this code, but it is for static account types:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            builder => builder.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator, Roles.ContentUploader));
            options.AddPolicy("Discount",
                builder => builder.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator));
        });
```

Comment: What is a "normal user"? How are you applying permission-based authorization?

Comment: i have many type of account in my program i save permission in the cookie
one of that account type is system user (normal) does't have any access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could write a custom policy like below to match your requirement.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("NonNormalUser", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            !context.User.IsInRole("Normal")));
});
```